# Determine what a wall switch does

Tags: electrical, wiring, walls

I have 2 wall switches in an electrical box, 1 controls the ceiling fan, and I cannot find out what the other one does.

I've tested everything in the room. It does not control the light in the fan, the fan speed, or the wall outlet nearest the wall switch, or any other wall outlet in the room. The house is 12 years old and I'm the original owner. I've never used this switch before.

I have no other issues like this or any other in the house so it would be extremely unusual for this to be an issue where the builder made a mistake.

Now I need this switch. What can I do?

Comment: Did you try BOTH outlets in each wall outlet?  Sometimes they're split

Answer (score 1):

A lot of ceiling fan boxes are wired with two switches so that one switch can control the lights and the other can control the fan motor.  Of course, when someone replaces a fan, or even when it's initially installed, it's not hooked up that way so one switch controls everything.

After you check all the other outlets in the room (both sides like Chris said), you can pull the canopy trim off the fan and look at the wires.  See if there is an extra wire capped off in the box.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tested both sides in all outlets in the room and the switch does not control them.

Comment: If I find a capped off wire after looking inside the canopy, what would I do with it? Connect it to this switch somehow, but how? I have to think this switch must control the light in the fan. It's the most logical option.

Comment: You can just leave the wire capped off - there's no harm in that.  If your fan has separate power wires for the light and motor (most do unless whoever installed it cut a wire too short or did a little rewiring), you can connect the light to the capped wire and leave the motor on the existing switch.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do... first of all, check if the wires of the second switch have voltage. If they have, try to disconnect the wires of the first switch and see what happens when you turn off/on the wires of the second switch. if nothing happens, you just could add a plug or something else I guess (check before the electrical codes of your Country). If happens something, just leave them that way (what I'd do). If they don't have voltage, you should check where the fault is located, and from them...

Answer (score 0):

(All references to 2 & 3 wire cables are always "plus ground".)

#### The Ceiling Fan/Light

Yes, even though it doesn't do that right now.

In the olden days, a fan/light combination would work one of two ways:

- Two switches - one for fan, one for light
- One switch for all power, pull chain for fan, pull chain for light

The first - two switches - is often preferred. But it requires 3 wires (2 switched hots, 1 neutral) and a typical ceiling *light only* fixture only needs 2 wires. So replacing a fan where only a light existed originally would mean you didn't have enough wires - and the solution was to connect everything at the fan (i.e., one switched hot to *both* the fan & light) and use the pull chains to control the fan & light separately.

The typical new setup has a wireless remote control which can give you the best of both worlds - only one hot or switched hot wire needed (plus neutral), so replacing a light-only fixture is OK even without running new wires - and separate control from a convenient location, with the remote often stuck in a holder on the wall right next to the wall switch.

In your case, the likely situation is that the room came with (or at some point was retrofitted with) a 3-wire cable, but the last fan/light installation was done *as if it was only a 2-wire cable*, either out of ignorance or because the current fan/light doesn't even use a 3rd wire (i.e., designed to *only* have fan/light switched separately through a remote or pull chains).

#### Trust, but Verify

Turn off power at the breaker and open the switch box. I suspect you will see something like:

- Cable 1

  - Black split (pigtail or daisy chain) to **both** switches.
  - White connected to white of second cable
- Cable 2

  - Black to 1st switch
  - Red to 2nd switch
  - White connected to white of first cable

If that's the case, if you open up the ceiling (I don't recommend doing this unless you have to repair/replace the fan), you will find the same 3-wire cable coming in, with the wire from the "does nothing" switch capped off instead of being connected to anything.

#### Making Use of the Switch

To use the "does nothing" switch, you will need to fish a new 2-wire cable between the switch and the device you want to control. If the circuit is a 20 Amp circuit then make sure to use 12 AWG wire, otherwise 14 AWG wire is OK. Black replaces the switched hot and white goes together with all the other whites.

#### Switch Loop?

If you have a switch loop: panel -> fan/light -> switch, then the configuration will be a bit different. You will know that is the case if you only have 1 3-wire (or 4-wire) cable into the box instead of 1 2-wire and 1 3-wire. If so, provide pictures and details and we'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly one of these things.

- It is a receptacle which is switched, after all.  **You did not realize outlets can be split and controlled separately** so you only checked one socket of each outlet.  The other one is swirched.
- It is a receptacle that *was* switched *once*, however the last guy found this dreadfully annoying (possibly because the whole outlet was switched, i.e. Not split). So he rejiggered it so it was not switched, by jumpering at the switch or at the outlet.
- It is a receptacle that *was* split and switched. However, *the last guy* changed out the receptacle for some reason (typically aesthetics), **and he did not understand how split outlets work, and failed to break off the tab**. As a result, he shorted/defeated the switch.

The answer is to check the switch, and every outlet in the room (it is often *not* the nearest to the switch; the switched outlet is the one the installer thinks is closest to where he thinks you'll want a lamp).

Answer (score 0):

I've tested each side of every outlet in the room and the switch does not control any of them.

I removed the canopy from the fan and there are 2 black wires and 1 blue wire capped off together, 2 white wires capped off together and 2 green wires capped off together, obviously ground wires.

I'm fairly handy but I admit some of the terminology in some of the answers received is unfamiliar to me and I am not an electrician. But I can certainly handle installing wall switches and ceiling fans and I installed this one although it was 12 years ago.

I attached photos of the wiring in the canopy and of the wall switches. The switch that controls the fan is on the right and the switch that I can't figure out what it does is on the left.

Thanks to everyone who responded and I hope I can figure this out with more help from you guys.